# Calculating the height of cylinder from user input radius in python

Tags: python

I have written some code in python where cylinder shape land will be created. The radius value will come from the user input. However, I want the height of cylinder to be calculated from the radius. I have come up with a fromula to do so but I am not sure how to put it in the code. It keeps giving me h is not defined errors.

```
def createLand(landRadius):
    '''Creates flat land, circle-shaped for city to be built on. 
    Extruded tunnels for rivers.

    landHeight(h)     : the height/thickness of the Land
    landRadius(r)     : the size/radius of the land
    zsubdivisions(sz) : the number of subdivisions along z axis for tunnel extrusion
    '''

    #Creates circle-shaped land, moves edges and faces around for tunnels
    land = cmds.polyCylinder(name='Land', sx=0, sy=0, sz=5, h=landRadius*0.2/4, r=landRadius);
    cmds.polyMoveEdge('Land.e[160:179]', s=(0.57, 0.57, 0.57));
    cmds.polyMoveEdge('Land.e[120:139]', s=(1.08, 1.08, 1.08));
    cmds.polyMoveEdge('Land.e[140:159]', s=(1.32, 1.32, 1.32));
    cmds.rotate(0, '15deg', 0, 'Land');

    #Tunnels extrusion
    cmds.polyExtrudeFacet('Land.f[120:139]', 'Land.f[160:179]', 'Land.f[105:106]', 'Land.f[115:116]', 'Land.f[100:101]', 'Land.f[110:111]', 'Land.f[145:146]', 'Land.f[155:156]', 'Land.f[140:141]', 'Land.f[150:151]', kft=True, ty=-h/2);
    cmds.polyMoveEdge('Land.e[110:111]', 'Land.e[115:116]', 'Land.e[100:101]', 'Land.e[105:106]', ty=-h/2);
    cmds.move(0, -h/2, 0, 'Land');
```

Comment: This is not clear. The height of a cylinder is independent from the radius of its base. `h is not defined` means that you are using a variable called `h` that has not been given a value. Indeed your function `createLand` does not take a parameter called `h`, although  it is used in its body.

Comment: where do you call this function ? can you post you code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you haven't defined 'h' as a variable. You do however set the 'h' argument in the `polyCylinder()` function. You may want to declare 'h' first.

```
h = landRadius*0.2/4;
land = cmds.polyCylinder(name='Land', sx=0, sy=0, sz=5, h=h, r=landRadius);
```

then later in the code when you have the following

```
cmds.polyExtrudeFacet('Land.f[120:139]', 'Land.f[160:179]', 'Land.f[105:106]', 'Land.f[115:116]', 
'Land.f[100:101]', 'Land.f[110:111]', 'Land.f[145:146]', 'Land.f[155:156]', 'Land.f[140:141]', 
'Land.f[150:151]', kft=True, ty=-h/2);
```

where you have `ty=-h/2`, 'h' will be defined.

Comment: Thank you. That is exacly what I needed. Now the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have

`land = cmds.polyCylinder(name='Land', sx=0, sy=0, sz=5, h=landRadius*0.2/4, r=landRadius);
<snip>
cmds.move(0, -h/2, 0, 'Land');`

Note that the `h=landRadius*0.2/4` in the first line sets the h argument to cmds.polyCylinder (I'm assuming it looks something like

`def polyCylinder(self,name,sx,sy,sz,h,r):
   #stuff`

This does NOT set h in the rest of your code.  I looks like you want to scale the height to be .  You can either do

`cmds.move(0, -landRadius*0.2/8, 0, 'Land');`

Or possibly 
`cmds.move(0, -land.h/2, 0, 'Land');`